# DSolve can't solve DSolve[f'[x] == InverseFunction[f][x], f[x], x]

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages

Here is the code I tried.

```
DSolve[f'[x] == InverseFunction[f][x], f[x], x]
```

The pop-up message is **DSolve::dvnoarg: The function f appears with no arguments.**

But I don't think this is a valid reason. I have the argument `x`.

Comment: If `f` has an argument `x`, it would appear as `f[x]`, not `InverseFunction[f][x]`.  The argument to `InverseFunction` is `f` without an `x`. The argument to `InverseFunction[f]` is `x`, but `x` is not an argument to `f`. You could try the equivalent `DSolve[f[f'[x]] == x, f[x], x]` to get a different error, indicating (imo) that `DSolve` does solve this type of equation (which is not an ODE in the normal sense as defined by standard textbooks, nor a DDE, but a more general functional differential equation).

Answer (score 6):

Here's a way to get ***a*** solution, which I arrived at after trying a fixed-point iteration à la Picard iteration:

```
eqn = f'[x] == InverseFunction[f][x];
Off[InverseFunction::ifun];
Block[{f = a #^k &, eqn0},
 eqn0 = PowerExpand@eqn;
 ksol = First@Solve[Exponent[#, x] & /@ eqn0 && k > 0, k];
 asol = First@Solve[eqn0 /. ksol /. x -> 1, a];
 f0 = f /. asol /. ksol
 ]
```

> ```
> (*
>   E^(((1 + Sqrt[5]) (Log[2] - Log[1 + Sqrt[5]]))/(3 + Sqrt[5])) *
>    #1^(1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5])) &
> *)
> ```

Check:

```
Simplify[eqn /. f -> f0]
On[InverseFunction::ifun];
```

> ```
> (*  True  *)
> ```